# Javascript / jQuery : Display an IE Only Modal ONCE per user, then do not display it again

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, modal-dialog

I have a check for IE on my site and if IE is being used it pops a Modal window after a 3 second timeout, suggesting that the user get chrome or firefox. There is also a button for  "Continue Anyway at my Own Risk". Basically what I'd like to achieve is using localStorage to determine if the user has seen the modal already, by having it trigger 2 things prior to the modal:

**First:** check to see if the localStorage item exists already

**if it exists:** don't display modal

**if it doesn't exist:** display modal, then save localStorage item so that the next visit it doesn't display again.

I know how to do this with Javascript but unfortunately am very new to jQuery so it all still kind of looks like moosh to me. How can I accomplish my goal with additions or adaptations to the following code:

```
   <!--[if lt IE 10]>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(setTimeout(function(){
                $('#ieModal').modal('show');
            },3000));
        </script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Your time is appreciated.

Comment: Well not all browser under IE10 support local storage. :) Issue #1

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
   <!--[if lt IE 10]>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(setTimeout(function(){
                if(!check_if_localStorage_item_exists()) {
                  //it doesn't exist!
                  $('#ieModal').modal('show'); //Lets show the modal
                  create_localStorage_item();
                 }
            },3000));
        </script>
    <![endif]-->
```

And then you can just code the localStorage methods using javascript, You could also use cookies which could be a better solution for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you are able to use cookies with Jquery. Go to the following URL and you will see a Jquery Plugin that deals with cookies. Cookies is compatible with all browsers.
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie